# Calculating closest distance to a third destination on the way between two destinations - mySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, distance, trigonometry

We have 3 destinations with latitude and longitude

Destination1 (lat1,lng1)
Destination2 (lat2,lng2)
Destination3 (lat3,lng3)

We have select to calculate the distance between 1 and 2

```
      $query->selectRaw("111.111 *
        DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(lat2))
             * COS(RADIANS(lat1))
             * COS(RADIANS(lng2 - lng1))
             + SIN(RADIANS(lat2))
             * SIN(RADIANS(lat1))))) AS distance")
```

How to calculate the closest distance to destination3 between destination1 and destination2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this formula :

> **Altitude in terms of the sides :**
>
> For any triangle with sides a, b, c and semiperimeter s = (a + b + c) / 2, the altitude from side a is given by
>
> [image: test]
>
> This follows from combining Heron's formula for the area of a triangle in terms of the sides with the area formula (1/2)×base×height, where the base is taken as side a and the height is the altitude from A.

Source: [Wikipedia - Altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)#Some_additional_altitude_theorems)